# Optimizing Julia performance when an interpolated function has to be accessed multiple times as global variable

Tags: function, global-variables, julia

I am trying to apply the following performance tips in my code concerning the global variable issue:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

As far as I understood, to improve performance, one should avoid the use of global variables (especially when they have to be called in big loops) by declaring them as `const`, trying to use them as local variables, or annotating the type every time when it is used.

Now I have an interpolated function (obtained through interpolating an array in `Interpolations.jl`) named `minus_func`, the type of which obtained through `typeof` function:

```
getfield(Main, Symbol("#minus_func#877")){Interpolations.Extrapolation{Float64,3,ScaledInterpolation{Float64,3,Interpolations.BSplineInterpolation{Float64,3,OffsetArrays.OffsetArray{Float64,3,Array{Float64,3}},BSpline{Cubic{Line{OnCell}}},Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}},BSpline{Cubic{Line{OnCell}}},Tuple{StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}},StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}},StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}}},BSpline{Cubic{Line{OnCell}}},Periodic{Nothing}},getfield(Main, Symbol("#get_periodic#875"))}
```

This `minus_func` is declared as a global variable, and will be called many times in a loop (and may be changed, so I don't prefer to declare it as a `const`). Is it possible to annotate its type when it's called such that the performance can be improved? If so, how? As in the following example, where `x` is annotated to the type `Vector{Float64}`:

```
global x = rand(1000)

function loop_over_global()
    s = 0.0
    for i in x::Vector{Float64}
        s += i
    end
    return s
end
```

So how do I improve the performance of the following code in the same way, given that `minus_func` is global?

```
function loop_over_global()
    s = 0.0
    for i in 1:1000
        s += minus_func(i, 1, 1)  # Let's say, the function takes three integer arguments
    end
    return s
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the global into a function argument, so that that function argument is not global:

```
using BenchmarkTools

function fminus(i, j, k)
    return i - k - j
end

minus_func = fminus

function loop_over_global()
    s = 0.0
    for i in 1:1000
        s += minus_func(i, 1, 1)
    end
    return s
end

function loop_over_global_witharg(f::Function)
    s = 0.0
    for i in 1:1000
        s += f(i, 1, 1)
    end
return s
end

@btime loop_over_global()
@btime loop_over_global_witharg(fminus)



  32.400 μs (1976 allocations: 30.88 KiB)
  949.958 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```